# How can I read part of appsettings.json as raw string in .net core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I use C# and .net core web api.
I have following appsettings.json:

[image: appsettings.json]

How can I read the red part (as is, without parsing - **raw text**) of this appsettings.json?

I know that I can put this in separate file and then read like this:

```
var googleServiceAccount = File.ReadAllText("GoogleServiceAccount.json");
```

But I want to put them in appsettings.json.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the problem you have. You can use `File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");` as well to read the file you want. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Progman, "part of a file" is not the same as "file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;


IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(@"C:\....\appsettings.json")
        .Build();

 List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> items = configuration
        .GetSection("Google:ServiceAccount")
        .Get<Dictionary<string, string>>()
        .ToList();

foreach (var item in items) Console.WriteLine($"({item.Key},{item.Value})");
```

or you can use dependency injection instead of configuration builder

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
{
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> items = configuration
        .GetSection("Google:ServiceAccount")
        .Get<Dictionary<string, string>>()
        .ToList();
.....
}
}
```

Comment: Yea, there is possibility to construct that manually like you wrote:             var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            var googleServiceAccountItems = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ExternalServices:Google:ServiceAccount").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            foreach (var item in googleServiceAccountItems) {
                sb.AppendLine($"\t\"{item.Key}\": \"{item.Value}\"");
            }
            sb.Append("}");
            GoogleServiceAccountString = sb.ToString(); but I think it is not okey, because values can have like '\n'

Comment: I mean special characters inside values like '\n' broke everything, and there are some for example in "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMI...

Comment: @KaMarius  What is your problem? You have to try my suggestion and telll if something is not working. YOU didn't mention any special charactesr s in your question but I don' t see how they can affect. Pls post the real code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement);` method to achieve your requirement:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.AppendLine("{"); 
var googleServiceAccountItems = _configuration.GetSection("Google:ServiceAccount").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>(); foreach (var item in googleServiceAccountItems) { sb.AppendLine($"\t\"{item.Key}\": \"{item.Value}\""); }
sb.Append("}");

var GoogleServiceAccountString = sb.ToString();
GoogleServiceAccountString = Regex.Replace(GoogleServiceAccountString, "\n|\r|\t", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Serge answer was closest, so I accepted it